# Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I use `SnackBar` after, the `await`.

So, It's showing error like this:

```
Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps
```

I used `if (!mounted)` this line to remove the error. It removed the problem **but, `SnackBar` is not showing. When complete the task**

My code here:

```
Future removeMethod() async {
    String res = await DatabaseMethods().idReject(widget.uid);
    if (res == "success") {
      if (!mounted) return;
      showSnackBar(context, "Job done!");
    } else {
      if (!mounted) return;
      showSnackBar(context, "Error!!");
    }
  }
```

showSnackBar is customWidget. code of it:

```
void showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String title) {
  final snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: CustomText(
      text: title,
      size: 16,
    ),
    backgroundColor: darkblueColor,
  );
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
}
```

What can I do about this?. I want to show snackbar after await.

Comment: seems the widget is detached from tree I think. Can you include a dummy widget that will reproduce the same error

Comment: You need to skip calling for context if you are no longer mounted (as in, navigated away from the page).  See State.mounted for details.

Answer (score 0):

This basic example works based on your snippets. Here a snackbar is called after the result of a future is returned (e.g. a database call). If this helps?

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SnackBarAfterFutureResult extends StatelessWidget {
  const SnackBarAfterFutureResult({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await removeMethod()
                  .then((value) => showSnackBar(context, value));
            },
            child: const Text('Database call')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void showSnackBar(BuildContext context, bool result) {
  String text = "Job done!";
  if (!result) {
    text = "Error!!";
  }
  final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(text), backgroundColor: Colors.blue);
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
}

Future<bool> removeMethod() async {
  //e.g. getting result from database call
  bool isSuccess = false;
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    isSuccess = Random().nextBool();
  });
  return isSuccess;
}
```

Comment: It also not work. show error -> Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

Comment: OK, can you paste more of the code so can get a fuller picture of what might be causing the error in your case? A Builder or FutureBuilder might be a solution.